# code working in maria Db but not in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a sql code and properly run in maria Db. The code is,

```
SELECT
    city.name as 'city',
    (SELECT    IFNULL(sum(r.quantity),0) 
     from      rooms r 
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT pr.id as prop_id, 
                       pr.name as prop_name, 
                       pr.actual_name as prop_actualname, 
                       pr.status as prop_status, 
                       c.name as city_name 
                from   properties pr 
                left join cities c 
                on     c.id = pr.city_id) pc 
     on    r.property_id = pc.prop_id  
     where r.price * 152 > 5000 
     and   pc.city_name=city 
     and pc.prop_status = 'Active') as '>5000'
FROM 
    (SELECT name FROM cities) city
```

My output is ,

[image]

But when run in mysql version 5.7 te output is,

[image]

Why the code is working half...?

Comment: is the data exactly the same in both databases?

Comment: yes.. the same database was used in both cases...

Comment: Can you pls provide us a sample dataset, the results produced by mariadb and MySQL from the 2 datasets? This way we can test our solutions. But my guess still is that your data is not the same.

Comment: Actually I have only one database dump and used that in two versions. So there is no doubt that the date is same in two cases. However sometimes when the code is executed in the first time in Mysql, it works. But from the second time onward only the first 4 rows results are coming... No idea what is happening....